# How to use Calculated column to check if time is between 2 times

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

If I have an end time of "12.30 PM", how do I use calculated column to check if this is between lunch time from 12pm-1pm. I want to display "Yes" if it falls between and "No" if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below formula:

```
IF(AND(TEXT([Date],"h")>="12",TEXT([Date],"h")<="13"),"Yes","NO")
```